# DefaultTabController without Scaffold?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use `DefaultTabController` in the middle of some widgets. So my `TabBar` could not be in `AppBar` and has to be down some widgets.
So my problem is when I use `TabBarView` it crashes...

So here's an example of Flutter sample but no found how to do it without `Scaffold`.

```
final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
  Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
  Tab(text: 'RIGHT')];
```

Code

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: myTabs.length,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: TabBar(
      tabs: myTabs,
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
        final String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            'This is the $label tab',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Here is another example of a TabBar I should do [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfuGj.png)

Real Code

```
class ProfileTabBarNavigation extends StatelessWidget {
 final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
   const Tab(text: kArtwork),
   const Tab(text: kPastJobs)];
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  initialIndex: 0,
  child: Padding(
    padding: kPaddingTabBar,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: kLightGrey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(50),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        TabBar(
          tabs: myTabs,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
          labelColor: Colors.black,
          unselectedLabelStyle: kBoldText,
          labelStyle: kBoldText,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          indicator: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        TabBarView(
          children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
            final String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                'This is the $label tab',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't use `DefaultTabController` in middle?

Comment: @Kahou I want to use it, and sorry for not expressing good, but when I use `TabBarView` it crashes...

Comment: 11 exceptions... 

RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: I see... please try the TabBar and TabBarView.

Comment: @Kahou One of my ideas was to use instead of `Scaffold`, `Column`, but has different errors...
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#ab47d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: @Kahou without `DefaultTabController`?

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: @Kahou Added at the bottom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap your `TabBarView` with [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

```
Expanded(
 child: TabBarView(//...),
),
```

Try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/335ba37a1e27b415b40c8e6f64af0341)

Comment: Not working :(
I have this error >RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: With Sizeboxed and putting a height doesn't crash... But the heigh could change depend on the content...

Comment: Could you please, pass the link of your DartPad?

Comment: I added.~~~~~~~

Comment: In the DartPad works but in my project doesn't work XD

Comment: I see the problem if you add in the class `MyApp` and put `child: Column(children:[Text('Hey'), ProfileTabBarNavigation()]),`, doesn't work

Comment: Replace `Column` with `Scaffold` in `DefaultTabController`. I updated DartPad.

Comment: But the problem was to insert `DefaultTabController` in the middle of some widgets, inside a `Column`

Comment: Yes, see the DartPad. It is after Text('Hey') in `Column`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't refresh the page and it appears the old one

Answer (score 1):

you can use defaultTabView in middle of screen or use one of this packages

[Bubble Tab Indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble_tab_indicator)

[MD2 Tab Indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/md2_tab_indicator)

Comment: Thanks for these packages. I would not used in this screen, but I could use it in another that I thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Create a stateful widget like below

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_text_to_image/utils/app_colors.dart';
  
  /*
  Title: TabBarWidget
  Purpose: To Display TabBar in a Screen
  Created On : 16/11/2022
  Last Updated on : 16/11/2022
  Author : Kalpesh Khandla
  */

  class TabBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String firstTabTxt;
  final String firstTabViewTxt;
  final String secondTabTxt;
  final String secondTabViewTxt;
  const TabBarWidget({
  super.key,
  required this.firstTabTxt,
  required this.secondTabTxt,
  required this.firstTabViewTxt,
  required this.secondTabViewTxt,
  });
  @override
  State
  <TabBarWidget>
  createState() => _TabBarWidgetState();
  }
  class _TabBarWidgetState extends State
  <TabBarWidget>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
  _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
  _tabController?.dispose();
  super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  height: 100,
  child: Column(
  children: [
  Container(
  height: 35,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  border: Border.all(
  color: AppColors.tabBorderColor,
  ),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
  5.0,
  ),
  ),
  child: TabBar(
  controller: _tabController,
  indicator: BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
  colors: [
  AppColors.waterMelonColor,
  AppColors.mangoColor,
  AppColors.azureColor,
  AppColors.sapphireColor,
  ],
  begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
  end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
  stops: [
  0.1,
  0.4,
  0.6,
  1.0,
  ],
  tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
  ),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
  2.0,
  ),
  ),
  labelColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
  unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.blackColor,
  tabs: [
  Tab(
  text: widget.firstTabTxt,
  ),
  Tab(
  text: widget.secondTabTxt,
  ),
  ],
  ),
  ),
  Expanded(
  child: TabBarView(
  controller: _tabController,
  children: [
  Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
  child: Column(
  children: [
  Text(
  widget.firstTabViewTxt,
  ),
  ],
  ),
  ),
  Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
  child: Column(
  children: [
  Text(
  widget.secondTabViewTxt,
  ),
  ],
  ),
  ),
  ],
  ),
  ),
  ],
  ),
  );
  }
  }

and use it like a below :


TabBarWidget(
firstTabTxt: "Tab1",
firstTabViewTxt: "Tab1 View",
secondTabTxt: "Tab1",
secondTabViewTxt: "Tab2 View",
),
```

Comment: the code is not formatted and is hard to follow, can you please use the tools to format this code section?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `TabBar` and `TabbarView` in a Column as long as the `TabBarView` is enclosed with an `Expanded` widget.

```
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      TabBar(...),
      Expanded(
        child: TabBarView(...),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```